# Making audio dialogue recording sharp

Tags: dialogue-recording

For starters, I am an amateur using Izotope RX7 Standard for noise reduction of cassette tapes which has  voice dialogue only...

Due to poor recording conditions, a lot of noise was induced in the recordings which is being successfully eliminated using the dehum, Spectral denoise and Voice de noise functions in Izoptope RX7 Standard.

The problem remains that the dialogue in some tapes is unintelligible (not due to low volume level but due to getting "rounded off").  Looking desperately for ways to "sharpen" the voice so that the dialogue can be made intelligible and hence recovered.

Kindly advise what functions and steps in Izotope RX 7 Standard application can help me perform this function.  Thanks!

Comment: Being able to examine a bit of the audio, cleaned & uncleaned, same segment, would be a useful start; otherwise we're just guessing. Depending on how bad the original audio is, you may have to try resynthesise, or just EQ… or it may not be possible.

Comment: @Tetsujin - much appreciate your kind guidance sir!  Appears to be a good path to move forward...